# DAX: How to correctly create a measure group from a range of dates?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset more or less like this one:

```
DATE       | VALUE
01/01/2011 | 100
02/01/2011 | 150
02/01/2011 | 550       --> Repeted on purpouse
.
.
12/01/2016 | 320
```

Now I need to have a calculated measure with only the values within a date range, I tried in many ways but with no success, the only one I managed to get it work is the follow DAX syntax:

```
consuntivo = CALCULATE(SUM(provadat[valori]);provadat[datazione]>=DATE(2015;01;01)&&provadat[datazione]<=DATE(2016;01;01))
```

but it generates the following:

[image]

So basically I need a DAX Query with distinct sum for each dates. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Two methods.

1. In the Table visualization you can choose `Sum` as the summarize option for the column `valori`.

[image: table]

2. Or using DAX, it'll be just simple as

   `consuntivo = SUM(provadat[valori])`

You don't need to handle the date logic particularly because Power BI will handle it based on the context (data columns you used with the measure).

[image: dax]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think that or I didn't explain myself or you didn't read the question very well..this is what I was trying to do in the answe below

Answer (score 0):

So basically what I was missing was to add filters.

```
xxx = Calculate(SUM(provadat[valori]);FILTER(VALUES(provadat);provadat[datazione] <= DATE(2017;01;01) && provadat[datazione] >= DATE(2016;01;01)))
```